# Hashflare plans

Tags: services

Can someone please explain me why is the SHA-256 plan cheaper than SCRYPT plan? If I understand it right, I will pay $7.50 for 1 MH/s with SCRYPT and only $1.50 for 10GH/s, which is much faster. What's the catch? And do you guys have any experience with payment? For example can I pay 12*$7.5 for year subscription at once and don't worry about anything every month? Or do they take the money from my bank account montly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because SCRYPT is a much more complex algorithm than SHA-256. Its more expensive to scale up SCRYPT-based systems, because they require a huge amount memory in addition to computing power.
You can't compare SCRYPT and SHA-256 in terms of hashpower, because they are different algorithms and are used for different coins.
For example, Bitcoin is based on SHA-256 while Litecoin is SCRYPT.

**Just a word of advice.** Cloud mining is never profitable, unless you are mining a new just-launched coin.
You can check the profitability here https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/btc?HashingPower=14&HashingUnit=TH%2Fs&PowerConsumption=0&CostPerkWh=0
Seriously, you are better off buying cryptocurrencies from an exchange.